# VLOOKUP on Calculated Cell Failing

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am new to using VLOOKUPS - I am having an issue where the value its pointing at (Cell E2) is a calculated cell in itself, the VLOOKUP only seems to work if I Hardcode a value into the cell.

Are there any ways I can get around this - I am surprised I couldn't find this on the Internet so far given it must be quite a common problem

VLOOKUP Code: =VLOOKUP(E2,'Colour Code'!A$2:B$11, 2, FALSE)

Formula in Cell E2: =LEFT(C2,1)

In this case the value thats calculated in E2 is "3" but the VLookup only works if I literally type "3" into the Cell, I get an #N/A error otherwise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shoudl use the value function like this:
`=VALUE(LEFT(C2,1))`

--OR--

`=VLOOKUP(VALUE(E2),'Colour Code'!A$2:B$11, 2, FALSE)`

The problem you are having is trying to match a number against a string.  This formula converts text to numbers.

Comment: Thank you!!! Thats it. I haven't met the Value function either so good to know thanks. Ill add as the answer in 7 minutes.

Comment: When I try to use `=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE([@BILLING],"/",""),"-",""))` The actual value of the cell becomes `=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE([@BILLING],"/",""),"-",""))` instead of the calculated value. Has this changed in Excel 2013?